# 404 not found with good .htaccess and only one some pages

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

My question is : what could generate a 404 with a correct permalink, a correct .htaccess and only on some kind of pages ???

- with default permalink, I can display all pages. OK
- with permalink like %postname%, some pages are working, some others not...
- pages associated with custom post types generated through a function are well displayed...
- pages with default post type generate a 404...

Of course, it was working at the beginning... But not now !
I made a big mistake and I already spent days without finding where :-(

If you have any idea, I will try to investigate.

Thousand thanks for that !

Comment: Check your logs. Check the URL format, check capitalization.

Comment: Seems obvious but make sure you go back to the Permalink Settings page and save it after any changes. Can you show us what your .htaccess looks like?

Comment: Have you disabled all plugins inorder to ensure its not any of them causing issues?

Comment: Hello all, sorry to be late.

Comment: Matt > It was working before, then not. So, not a capitalization issue.

Comment: Hello JDev518 > here is my .htacess : 

Options +FollowSymlinks\nRewriteEngine on


# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: Sorry... Strange editor here... Don't know how to create a new line...

Comment: Phill Healey, hello. Yes, I disabled plugins one by one... Nothing better

Comment: Hello, 
I found the problem :

It cames from WooCommerce permalinks parameters : I removed all terms I input and set them back to default and its OK.